# Not connecting GRPC requist using aws nlb with ACM cert

Tags: kubernetes, grpc, nginx-ingress, envoyproxy

I have k8s cluster for using gRPC service with envoy proxy, all gRPC and web request collect Envoy and passed into backend , Envoy SVC started with nlb, and nlb attached with ACM certificate. without nlb certificate request passed into backend correctly and getting response, but need to use nlb-url:443, again if I'm attaching ACM cert into nlb,and its not at all getting response. why?
Or again I need to use another ingress for treat ssl and route?

```
envoy-svc.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-backend-protocol: http
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-cross-zone-load-balancing-enabled: "true"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-cert: arn:aws:acm:eu-west-2:12345676789:certificate/ss304s07-3ss2-4s73-8744-bs2sss123460
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type: nlb
  creationTimestamp: "2021-06-11T02:50:24Z"
  finalizers:
  - service.kubernetes.io/load-balancer-cleanup
  name: envoy-service
  namespace: default
spec:
  externalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  ports:
  - nodePort: 31156
    port: 443
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 80
  selector:
    name: envoy
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: LoadBalancer
```

---

```
envoy-conf
    admin:
      access_log_path: /dev/stdout
      address:
        socket_address: { address: 0.0.0.0, port_value: 8801 }
    static_resources:
      # https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/v1.15.0/api-v3/config/listener/v3/listener.proto#config-listener-v3-listener
      listeners:
        - name: listener_0
          address:
            socket_address:
              address: 0.0.0.0
              port_value: 80
          filter_chains:
            - filters:
                - name: envoy.filters.network.http_connection_manager
                  typed_config:
                    # https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/v1.15.0/api-v3/extensions/filters/network/http_connection_manager/v3/http_connection_manager.proto#extensions-filters-network-http-connection-manager-v3-httpconnectionmanager
                    "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.network.http_connection_manager.v3.HttpConnectionManager
                    stat_prefix: ingress_http
                    http2_protocol_options: {}
                    access_log:
                   # https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/v1.15.0/api-v3/extensions/access_loggers/file/v3/file.proto
                   #
                   # You can also configure this extension with the qualified
                   # name envoy.access_loggers.http_grpc
                   # https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/v1.15.0/api-v3/extensions/access_loggers/grpc/v3/als.proto
                      - name: envoy.access_loggers.file
                        typed_config:
                          # https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/v1.15.0/api-v3/extensions/access_loggers/file/v3/file.proto#extensions-access-loggers-file-v3-fileaccesslog
                          "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.access_loggers.file.v3.FileAccessLog
                          # Console output
                          path: /dev/stdout
                    route_config:
                      name: local_route
                      virtual_hosts:
                        - name: local_service
                          domains:
                            - "*"
                          routes:
                            - match:
                                prefix: /
                                grpc:
                              route:
                                cluster: greeter_service
                          cors:
                            allow_origin_string_match:
                              - prefix: "*"
                            allow_methods: GET, PUT, DELETE, POST, OPTIONS
                            # custom-header-1 is just an example. the grpc-web
                            # repository was missing grpc-status-details-bin header
                            # which used in a richer error model.
                            # https://grpc.io/docs/guides/error/#richer-error-model
                            allow_headers: accept-language,accept-encoding,user-agent,referer,sec-fetch-mode,origin,access-control-request-headers,access-control-request-method,accept,cache-control,pragma,connection,host,name,x-grpc-web,x-user-agent,grpc-timeout,content-type
                            expose_headers: grpc-status-details-bin,grpc-status,grpc-message,authorization
                            max_age: "1728000"
                    http_filters:
                      - name: envoy.filters.http.grpc_web
                        # This line is optional, but adds clarity to the configuration.
                        typed_config:
                          # https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/v1.15.0/api-v3/extensions/filters/http/grpc_web/v3/grpc_web.proto
                          "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.grpc_web.v3.GrpcWeb
                      - name: envoy.filters.http.cors
                        typed_config:
                          # https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/v1.15.0/api-v3/extensions/filters/http/cors/v3/cors.proto
                          "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.cors.v3.Cors
                      - name: envoy.filters.http.grpc_json_transcoder
                        typed_config:
                          "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.grpc_json_transcoder.v3.GrpcJsonTranscoder
                          proto_descriptor: "/etc/envoy-sync/sync.pb"
                          ignore_unknown_query_parameters: true
                          services:
                            - "com.tk.system.sync.Synchronizer"
                          print_options:
                            add_whitespace: true
                            always_print_primitive_fields: true
                            always_print_enums_as_ints: true
                            preserve_proto_field_names: true
                      - name: envoy.filters.http.router
                        typed_config:
                          # https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/v1.15.0/api-v3/extensions/filters/http/router/v3/router.proto
                          "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.router.v3.Router
      clusters:
        # https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/v1.15.0/api-v3/config/cluster/v3/cluster.proto#config-cluster-v3-cluster
        - name: greeter_service
          type: LOGICAL_DNS
          connect_timeout: 0.25s
          lb_policy: round_robin
          load_assignment:
            cluster_name: greeter_service
            endpoints:
              - lb_endpoints:
                  - endpoint:
                      address:
                        socket_address:
                          address: micro-deployment
                          port_value: 8081
          http2_protocol_options: {} # Force HTTP/2
```

Comment: Is acm cert in the same region as cluster?

Comment: yes.. ACM is the same region, and i can see the cert details  in nlb listeners filed.